# How do I let Python see what Terminal outputs when I enter a command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, terminal, macos-sierra

I want to run a program on Python on macOS Sierra that checks Terminal for its outputs after I automatically enter a command on it. For example, I would write in Terminal:

```
$ pwd
```

and then Terminal would output something like:

```
/Users/username
```

How would I have Python scan what Terminal outputs and set it to a variable as a string?

```
>>>output = (whatever Terminal outputs)
>>>print (output)
"/Users/username"
```

By the way, the other forums do not explain in much detail how one would do this in macOS. Therefore, this is not a duplicate of any forum.

Comment: You can manipulate `stdout` using `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Are you trying to run `pwd` from within a Python script? (In that specific case, `os.getcwd()` is what you want.) Or do you want to hook your shell? Or Terminal.app specifically? It would help if you described what exactly you're trying to do... I suspect that this is an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe the output to a file and read the file.

```
$ pwd > output.txt
```

Then read the file and take further actions based on its contents.

Comment: Wow, that way actually helps a lot thanks! By the way, could you upvote my question? Because I guess people dislike questions when they can't answer them as sufficiently as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, it has some shortcut methods to make things easier and less complicated than using `Popen`.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.check_output("pwd")
>>> print(output)
b'L:\\\r\n'
```

You can decode this using `output.decode("UTF-8")` if you like or you can use the `universal_newlines` keyword argument to have it done automatically as well as sorting out newlines.

```
>>> subprocess.check_output("pwd", universal_newlines=True)
'L:\\\n'
```

*Edit:* With [@Silvio's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288659/silvio-mayolo) sensible suggestion, passing all arguments you can do the following:

```
subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l"])
```

Or if you have a string sourced from elsewhere you can call `.split()` which will generate a list of substrings separated by a space.

```
subprocess.check_output("ls -l /".split())
```

Note: I'm using Python3 on Windows and [Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) so I have `\r\n` line endings and `pwd`.

Comment: It works for "pwd" but it doesn't work for things like "ls /Applications" or "sudo pwd". Anything I could do to fix that?

Comment: you can try adding `shell=True` to the function call. However there are [implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess), so you should make sure you sanitise your inputs.

Comment: As an alternative to `shell=True`, consider passing your arguments as a list. `subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "pwd"])`. That's a cleaner, safer way to invoke the shell.